# Namenode HA (UnknownHostException: nameservice1)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager, cloudera-cdh

We enable Namenode High Availability through Cloudera Manager, using

Cloudera Manager >> HDFS >> Action > Enable High Availability >> Selected Stand By Namenode & Journal Nodes
 Then nameservice1

Once the whole process completed then Deployed Client Configuration.

Tested from Client Machine by listing HDFS directories (hadoop fs -ls /) then manually failover to standby namenode & again listing HDFS directories (hadoop fs -ls /). This test worked perfectly.

But When I ran hadoop sleep job using following command it failed

```
$ hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.6.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.26/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-examples.jar sleep -m 1 -r 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:129)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:448)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:410)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:128)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2308)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:87)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2342)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2324)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:351)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:980)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:974)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:974)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:948)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1410)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.SleepJob.run(SleepJob.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.SleepJob.run(SleepJob.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.SleepJob.main(SleepJob.java:165)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
... 37 more
```

I dont know why its not able to resolved nameservice1 even after deploying client configuration.

When I google this issue I found only one solution to this issue

Add the below entry in configuration entry for fix the issue
dfs.nameservices=nameservice1
dfs.ha.namenodes.nameservice1=namenode1,namenode2
dfs.namenode.rpc-address.nameservice1.namenode1=ip-10-118-137-215.ec2.internal:8020
dfs.namenode.rpc-address.nameservice1.namenode2=ip-10-12-122-210.ec2.internal:8020
dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.nameservice1=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider

My impression was Cloudera Manager take cares of it. I checked client for this configuration & configuration was there (/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/1998-deploy-client-config/hadoop-conf/hdfs-site.xml).

Also some more details of config files :

```
[11:22:37 root@datasci01.dev:~]# ls -l /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.*
/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs:
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  943 Jul 31 09:33 core-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2546 Jul 31 09:33 hadoop-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1577 Jul 31 09:33 hdfs-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  314 Jul 31 09:33 log4j.properties

/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs1:
total 20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  233 Sep  5  2013 container-executor.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1890 May 21 15:48 core-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2546 May 21 15:48 hadoop-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1577 May 21 15:48 hdfs-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  314 May 21 15:48 log4j.properties

/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce:
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1032 Jul 31 09:33 core-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2775 Jul 31 09:33 hadoop-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1450 Jul 31 09:33 hdfs-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  314 Jul 31 09:33 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2446 Jul 31 09:33 mapred-site.xml

 /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1:
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  233 Sep  5  2013 container-executor.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1979 May 16 12:20 core-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2775 May 16 12:20 hadoop-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1450 May 16 12:20 hdfs-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  314 May 16 12:20 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2446 May 16 12:20 mapred-site.xml
[11:23:12 root@datasci01.dev:~]#
```

I doubt its issue with old configuration in /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs1 & /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1 , but not sure.

looks like /etc/hadoop/conf/* never got updated

```
# ls -l /etc/hadoop/conf/
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  233 Sep  5  2013 container-executor.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1979 May 16 12:20 core-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2775 May 16 12:20 hadoop-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1450 May 16 12:20 hdfs-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  314 May 16 12:20 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2446 May 16 12:20 mapred-site.xml
```

Anyone has any idea about this issue?

Comment: Dont know why its symlink to wrong config http://pastebin.com/mv1ehRCm   Can we change thoes symlink to correct config manually ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are using wrong client configuration in /etc/hadoop/conf directory. Sometimes Cloudera Manager (CM) deploy client configurations option may not work.

As you have enabled NN HA, you should have valid core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files in your hadoop client configuration directory. For getting the valid site files, Go to HDFS service from CM  Choose **Download client configuration** option from the **Actions** Button. you will get configuration files in zip format, extract the zip files and replace /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml and /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml files with the extracted core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml files.

Comment: then use the second option(Download client configuration and replace site files) as mentioned in the answer

Comment: I fixed it by removing alternative link

Comment: I do not have such problem but still it does not work in presto

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved. wrong config was linked to "/etc/hadoop/conf/" --> "/etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf/" --> "/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1"

It has to be "/etc/hadoop/conf/" --> "/etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf/" --> "/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce"

Answer (score 0):

below statement in my code resolved problem by specifying the host and port

```
val dfs = sqlContext.read.json("hdfs://localhost:9000//user/arvindd/input/employee.json")
```

Answer (score -4):

I resolved this issue my putting the complete line to create RDD

myfirstrdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://192.168.35.132:8020/BUPA.txt")

and then I was able to do other RDD transformation .. Make sure you have the w/r/x to the file or you can do chmod 777