# Accessing HDFS HA from spark job (UnknownHostException error)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, mesos, mesosphere

I have Apache Mesos 0.22.1 cluster (3 masters & 5 slaves), running Cloudera HDFS  (2.5.0-cdh5.3.1) in HA configuration and Spark 1.5.1 framework.

When I try to spark-submit compiled HdfsTest.scala example app (from Spark 1.5.1 sources) - it fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs` error in executor logs. This error is only observed when I pass HDFS HA Path as an argument `hdfs://hdfs/<file>`, when I pass `hdfs://namenode1.hdfs.mesos:50071/tesfile` - everything works fine.

What I've found after enabling TRACE logging is that Spark driver actually reads `hdfs://hdfs` URL correctly, but Spark executor - doesn't.

My Scala app code:

```
import org.apache.spark._
object HdfsTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HdfsTest")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val file = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val mapped = file.map(s => s.length).cache()
    for (iter <- 1 to 10) {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
      for (x <- mapped) { x + 2 }
      val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
      println("Iteration " + iter + " took " + (end-start) + " ms")
    }
    sc.stop()
   }
  }
```

I compile this code and submit jar file to Spark in cluster mode:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class com.cisco.hdfs.HdfsTest http://1.2.3.4/HdfsTest-0.0.1.jar hdfs://hdfs/testfile
```

My spark-defaults.conf file:

```
spark.master                     spark://1.2.3.4:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.driver.memory              1g
```

My spark-env.sh file:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/spark
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/spark/conf
```

I have spark deployed on each slave in /opt/spark directory.

I can accesses HDFS using "hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://hdfs/" command in console, without the need to specify active namenode address and port.

```
core-site.xml:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://hdfs</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

hdfs-site.xml:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.nameservice.id</name>
  <value>hdfs</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
  <value>hdfs</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.hdfs</name>
  <value>nn1,nn2</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hdfs.nn1</name>
  <value>namenode1.hdfs.mesos:50071</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.hdfs.nn1</name>
  <value>namenode1.hdfs.mesos:50070</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hdfs.nn2</name>
  <value>namenode2.hdfs.mesos:50071</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.hdfs.nn2</name>
  <value>namenode2.hdfs.mesos:50070</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hdfs</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider      </value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
     <value>qjournal://journalnode1.hdfs.mesos:8485;journalnode2.hdfs.mesos:8485;journalnode3.hdfs.mesos:8485/hdfs</value>
   </property>

 <property>
   <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>master.mesos:2181</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
  <value>/var/lib/hdfs/data/jn</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:///var/lib/hdfs/data/name</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:///var/lib/hdfs/data/data</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
  <value>shell(/bin/true)</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
  <value>10485760</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.balance.bandwidthPerSec</name>
  <value>41943040</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct</name>
   <value>0.90</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval</name>
  <value>60000</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.handler.count</name>
  <value>10</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.handler.count</name>
  <value>20</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.image.compress</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.image.compression.codec</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.invalidate.work.pct.per.iteration</name>
  <value>0.35f</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.replication.work.multiplier.per.iteration</name>
  <value>4</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
  <value>false</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
   <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.streams.cache.size</name>
  <value>1000</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.streams.cache.size.expiry.ms</name>
   <value>1000</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
  <value>/var/run/hadoop-hdfs/dn._PORT</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution - adding

```
spark.files file:///opt/spark/conf/hdfs-site.xml,file:///opt/spark/conf/core-site.xml
```

to `conf/spark-defaults.conf` on each slave solves the problem.

After that executors successfully download `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` from driver program to executor program.

Comment: Awesome! Can you please accept this as the correct answer?

Comment: The more correct solution is to distribute `spark-env.sh` and `/opt/spark/conf` to the slaves

Answer (score 4):

Spark internally will use default conf available for **fs.defaultFS**, which is your local `file://`.

in-order it to honor HDFS HA you need to pass both `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` to the `SparkContext` via the CLASSPATH, or as below (make sure these files available in the local slave nodes in the same location eg: `/config/core-site.xml`

For example, Spark 1.x

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

Spark 2.x

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext()
```

In either case,

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration().addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/config/core-site.xml"));
sc.hadoopConfiguration().addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/config/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

Comment: These files are already picked out of `src/main/resources`. What is the property that actually allows HA configurations to get resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to invoke spark-submit using the following:

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf spark-submit
```

This configures spark correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From a very basic IntelliJ project (not using `spark-submit`) , I verified these are the only settings you need on the CLASSPATH of your application.

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hdfscluster</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hdfscluster</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
        <value>hdfscluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.hdfscluster</name>
        <value>nn1,nn2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hdfscluster.nn1</name>
        <value>namenode1.fqdn:8020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hdfscluster.nn2</name>
        <value>namenode2.fqdn:8020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**Main.java**

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[*]") // "yarn-client"
            .getOrCreate();

    spark.read().text("hdfs:///tmp/sample.txt");
}
```

You'll also need a `yarn-site.xml` if you want to submit via YARN, but I see your question mentions Mesos

Answer (score -4):

`java.net.UnknownHostException` indicates that the host with provide name `hdfs` in this case can not be resolved to an IP Address.

[What causes the error - java.net.UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/what-causes-the-error-java-net-unknownhostexception)

You could try to check if does resolve to an IP address `ping hdfs`.

Comment: Actually, "hdfs" here is HA nameservice name, not a hostname. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html.

Comment: Eventually, `hdfs` is not a hostname. So, it shouldn't reach to the underlying Java API. There is something wrong with your HA configuration - try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062788/namenode-ha-unknownhostexception-nameservice1

Comment: This answer is completely ignoring the context of the question and does not address anything.

Comment: @kyarovoy  @KomradeP.: If you read carefully the full url in question is `hdfs://hdfs/<file>` where, middle `hdfs` is being resolved, which causes the exception https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html