# Remote mysql Database access error using spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Accessing Table from remote mysql database, which works fine locally from eclipse but throwing error while trying from `spark-submit`.

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: namenode
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:378)
```

Spark-submit below:

```
spark-submit \
--jars /home/hduser/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.1.jar \
--class "retail.stack" --master local[2] \
--driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 2 \
sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar \
/home/hduser/spark-training/workspace/demos/output/extra_in_src \
/home/hduser/spark-training/workspace/demos/output/extradest \
/home/hduser/spark-training/workspace/demos/output/bestMatch
```

Code Below:

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Database")
  .getOrCreate()

val jdbcUsername = "root"
val jdbcPassword = "root"
val url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.175.35:3306/sample?useSSL=false"

val connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", jdbcUsername)
connectionProperties.put("password", jdbcPassword)

 val querySource = "(select * from source1) as src"
val queryDestination = "(select * from destination1) as dest"

val source = spark.read.jdbc(url, querySource, connectionProperties).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
val destination = spark.read.jdbc(url, queryDestination, connectionProperties).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
```

Thank you

Comment: can you please share the code what you have tried ?

Comment: @senthilkumarp code updated..!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174386/accessing-hdfs-ha-from-spark-job-unknownhostexception-error please see this

Comment: I'm accessing mysql, why should I need to add those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by reconfiguring the Connection string. It worked fine.!