# Hadoop: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop-slave-2

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, openstack

I have created a hadoop cluster with 1 Master and 2 Slaves. I am running it with minimum specifications in the *-site.xml files.

*core-site.xml*

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://10.0.0.51:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

*hfds-site.xml*

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
        <value>~/DNfiles</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

*mapred-site.xml*

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

*yarn-site.xml*

```xml
<configuration>

    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>10.0.0.51:8025</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>10.0.0.51:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>10.0.0.51:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The problem is I am able to format namenode, put files into hfs and all but when i run a simple example i get the following error.

```
Container launch failed for container_1455133326738_0002_02_000007 : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop-slave-2 at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.setTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.convertFromYarn(ConverterUtils.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy$ContainerManagementProtocolProxyData.newProxy(ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.java:266)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy$ContainerManagementProtocolProxyData.<init>(ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.getProxy(ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl.getCMProxy(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop-slave-2
```

While the programs goes on to finish by working with other slave i.e. 1 slave is reachable but other is not though they have the same configurations.
Since i am able to format and all so i am assuming my /etc/hosts file in master node is fine. Here is its snippet.

```bash
ubuntu@hadoop-master-1:~/hadoop-2.7.1/bin$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.51 hadoop-master-1
10.0.0.36 hadoop-slave
10.0.0.38 hadoop-slave-2
10.0.0.39 hadoop-slave-1
10.0.0.40 hadoop-slave-3
10.0.0.41 hadoop-slave-4
```

host file for slave

```bash
ubuntu@hadoop-slave-1:~/hadoop-2.7.1/bin$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.39 hadoop-slave-1
10.0.0.51 hadoop-master-1
```

Does anyone has any idea what could be the issue? Any help or possible pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you also post the hosts file for slave 2? Os it the same as what you posted for slave?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Its the same. it has got the master ip address too.

Comment: Does it not have to have a different ip-address for slave 2?

Comment: Here is the file. they have different ip addresses `ubuntu@hadoop-slave-2:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.36 hadoop-slave-2
10.0.0.51 hadoop-master-1`

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062788/namenode-ha-unknownhostexception-nameservice1) has some answers that might help

Comment: I have added my *-site.xml files too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue lies in the /etc/hosts file of the slaves. The reason there were no errors while putting file and formatting namenode is that the master communicates to all the slaves and it has ip addresses for all of them. But once you run an application on the cluster, the Application master is created on one of the slaves. AM then through slave has to communicate with other slaves. Since slave’s host file does not have their address (judging by the posted hosts file for slaves) it is giving an Unknown host error.

As rule of thumb, make sure all the nodes in the cluster have ip addresses to every other node in the cluster. Fix this and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

UnknownHostException error while running Hadoop application

Tested on hadoop 2.7.7. Created 4 ubuntu VMs on Ubuntu host.
1 VM as namenode
3 VMs as datanodes.

UnknownHostexception got removed when /etc/hosts table updated with the ip addresses of all the nodes.

Example:
192.168.2.7     namenode 
192.168.2.11    datanode1
192.168.2.12    datanode2
192.168.2.13    datanode3